# Одно и два "н" в прилагательных. Как объяснить правописание?

Tags: орфография, прилагательные

*Ветряные  мельницы в Амстердаме.*

Почему в этом случае пишется одна "н"?

Answer (score 2):

**ВЕТРЯНОЙ**,  Приводимый в действие силой ветра. В. насос. В-ая электростанция. В-ая мельница.

**Ветер —  ветряной,** для образования  прилагательного используется отыменный суффикс ЯН с одной буквой Н, исключение: *стеклянный, оловянный, деревянный*.

Надо отличать от глагольного суффикса ЕН/ЕНН:  (*ветрить*) —  **ветреный** день, человек (нет приставки), **безветренный** день, **обветренное** лицо (приставка БЕЗ, ОБ).